# cudaEventElapsedTime and nvprof runtime

Tags: cuda

Consider the following kernel

```
__global__ void elementAccess( int *a, int N )
{
  int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
  int z = a[ i ];
}
```

Which is called by

```
cudaEvent_t start, stop;
float elapsedTime;
cudaEventCreate(&start);
cudaEventRecord(start,0);

elementAccess<<< 1, 1>>>( d_A, 1 );

cudaEventCreate(&stop);
cudaEventRecord(stop,0);
cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
cudaEventElapsedTime(&elapsedTime, start,stop);

printf("Elapsed time : %f ms\n" ,elapsedTime);
```

Where `d_A` is an integer array.

When I run the code in terminal, I see

```
Elapsed time : 0.015328 ms
```

When I profile it with  `nvprof --metrics SOME_METRICS -o e.nvvp ./element_access`, I see that kernel duration is `2.95 us`.

So, why the clock events say the kernel runtime is 15us while nvvp says it is 2.95us?

Are they two different things? Or something else is missing?

Comment: `cudaEventCreate` may be affecting this.  You should not do that in the timing region.   Do all of your event creation before doing any `cudaEventRecord` operation

Comment: Has no effect actually. I mean `cudaEventRecord(start,0); /* kernel */; cudaEventRecord(stop,0);` takes about the same time. About 15us.

Answer (score 2):

Your first measurement (based on elapsed time) includes kernel launch overhead.
The second (based on CUDA events) mostly excludes the launch overhead.

Given that your kernel does absolutely nothing (the single memory load will be optimized away for lack of subsequent use of the value), it appears reasonable that the elapsed time consists almost entirely of launch overhead.

Comment: I see similar methods for measuring access latency. For example, I want to measure the memory latency. That means kernel launch overhead is always present.